# Comparing cells in excel with the same text but different order

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to compare text between two cells in excel however, the text is not in the same order. For example Cell 1 = G1, G60, G25 and Cell 2 = G60, G25, G1.
The text is essentially the same however <if cell 1 = cell 2> formula will result in false.
Is there any way to compare the two cells that would bring back a TRUE result?

Comment: In your specific example I would probably use a combination of `textsplit` and `sort` and `=`. I would then wrap with `if` or `countif` depending on full match or partial match. My suggestion would NOT work for different text lengths in the different celss.

Comment: Could you please show us a simple sample for better understanding? Thx ~

Answer (score 0):

The formula `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SORT(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,","))))=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SORT(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A2,,","))))` would work.

- Splits text by the `,`.
- Removes any extra spaces.
- Sorts the text.
- Re-joins the text and compares with the same operation on the other cell.

[image]